# PHP: how to subtract e.g 9 days from filectime()

Tags: php

I want to delete all files older than 9 days. Since filectime returns the creation time of a

certain file, therefore, I just want to know how to subtract for an example: 9 days from the

filectime().

**Code**:

```
<?php
 $filename = 'JSONFormate.json';
 if (file_exists($filename)) {
echo "$filename was last changed: " . date("F D Y H:i:s.", filectime
($filename));
echo "\n......".filectime($filename)-777600;
}
?>
```

**Result**
JSONFormate.json was last changed: May Tue 2012 22:50:10.-777600

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract 777600 ([9 days in seconds](http://www.google.co.uk/search?ix=sea&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=9%20days%20in%20seconds)) from the result of `filectime()`

Comment: The link in the answer shows you how to work out the number of seconds. Or you can just do 60*60*24*9 = 777600

Comment: please check the modification i posted now. i receive the posted results

Comment: Try putting filectime($filename)-777600 in brackets?

Answer (score 2):

[filectime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php) returns the last modified time of a file, not creation.

Also you do not want to take 9 days off the `filectime()`. What you want to do is remove 9 days from now and see if it's larger than the returned `filectime()`

```
int $last_modified = filectime("...");
int $nine_days_ago = time() - 777600;
if($nine_days_ago < $last_modified) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a unix command like this one `find . -name "*.trc"  -mtime +9 -exec rm -rf {} \;`
You can make a cronjob or even run it within PHP using "`" (backticks) or exec or system

Answer (score 0):

filectime returns a unixtimestamp. If you calculate the unixtimestamp for 9 days. then you can substract the unixtimestamp for 9 days from the unixtimestap u recieved from the filectime. then you get a unixtimestamp that is older than 9 days.

Then you check all the files with a lower timestamp then the calculated one.